# String value is being wrapped with {}

Tags: apex

Hi I am trying to replace one string value with another however my string is being wrapped with {} and I don't know why and causes the replace not to be able to find the string in my ETF_Summary__c field. How can I stop this from happening so the replace will work?

```
public static void ETFSummaryupdate(ETF__c[] etfnew){
    boolean etfnameamount = false;
    boolean updatefundslist = false;
    Set<String> relatedfundID = new Set<String>();
    Set<String> newETFNameAmount = new Set<String>();
    Set<String> oldETFNameAmount = new Set<String>();

    for(ETF__c etf : etfnew){
        ETF__c oldetf = (ETF__c)Trigger.oldMap.get(etf.Id);
        if(etf.Name != oldetf.name && etf.ETF_Amount__c != oldetf.ETF_Amount__c){
            etfnameamount = true;
            relatedfundID.add(etf.Related_Funds_to_Trade__c);
            oldETFNameAmount.add(oldetf.Name + ' $' + oldetf.ETF_Amount__c);
            newETFNameAmount.add(etf.Name + ' $' + etf.ETF_Amount__c);
        }
    }
    list<Funds_to_Trade__c> relatedFundslist = new list<Funds_to_Trade__c>();
    relatedFundslist = [select Id, Name, ETF_Summary__c from Funds_to_Trade__c where ID in: relatedfundID];
    for(Funds_to_Trade__c fund : relatedFundslist){
        if(etfnameamount == true){
            fund.ETF_Summary__c = fund.ETF_Summary__c.replace(string.valueof(oldETFNameAmount),string.valueof(newETFNameAmount));
        }
    }
        if(relatedFundslist.size() == 0){

        }
    if(relatedFundslist.size() > 0 && updatefundslist == false){
        update relatedFundslist;
        updatefundslist = true;            
    }

}
```

Comment: I think Its because oldETFNameAmount and newETFNameAmount are Set variables. So are you trying to replace a set of values with another set of values? I don't think this is the best way to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to convert the `Set`to `String` using temp `List`. So you will avoid the braces:

```
List<String> tmpList = new List<String>();
tmpList.addAll(oldETFNameAmount);
String stringFromSet = String.join(tmpList, ',');
```

But better work with sets methods `addAll(...)` and `removeAll(...)` instead of replacing strings. Assuming the value in the field `fund.ETF_Summary__c` is a semicolon-separated string:

```
// Creating a temp set. We will use it lates to assign back to the field
String val = fund.ETF_Summary__c;
Set<String> tempSet = new Set<String>();
tempSet.addAll(val.split(';'));

for(Funds_to_Trade__c fund : relatedFundslist){
    if(etfnameamount == true){      

        // Remove old values form the set
        tempSet.removeAll(oldETFNameAmount);
        // Add new values
        tempSet.addAll(newETFNameAmount);
    }
}

// Converting set to list to be able to "export" values to the string
List<String> tempList = new List<String>();
tempList.addAll(tempSet);

// Assigning a new value to the field (semicolon separated string)
fund.ETF_Summary__c = String.join(tempList, ';');
```

Comment: I also saw that you use assigned the val = fund.ETF_Summary__c before fund has been declared.

Comment: So I used your method of remove all and add all, it works for adding the value but does not remove my old value.

Comment: Figured it out, I was separating the field by line break but didn't update the split to \n and only the join to \n so thats why the add worked but not the remove. I also added everything above to within the for loop as you have used fund above and below it.